# Fill out NA values in Pandas DataFrame by using another Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                  'value1': ["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"],
                  'value2': [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5],
                    'value3': [1,2,3, None , None, None, None, None],
                    'value4': [1,2,3,None , None, None, None, None],
                    'value5': [1,2,3,None , None, None, None, None]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                  'value1': ["k","j","l","m","x","y"],
                  'value2': [2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5],
                  'value3': [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'value4': [3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                  'value5': [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df1 = 
  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
0      a       1     1.0     1.0     1.0
1      a       2     2.0     2.0     2.0
2      a       3     3.0     3.0     3.0
3      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
4      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
5      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
6      c       5     NaN     NaN     NaN
7      c       5     NaN     NaN     NaN

df2 = 
  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
0      k       2       2       3       2
1      j       2       2       2       1
2      l       1       2       2       2
3      m       3       3       3       3
4      x       4       4       4       4
5      y       5       5       5       5
```

I would like to fill NaN  in df1 from values in df2

So the results of df1 will look like

```
df1 = 
  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
0      a       1     1.0     1.0     1.0
1      a       2     2.0     2.0     2.0
2      a       3     3.0     3.0     3.0
3      b       4     2       2       1
4      b       4     2       2       2
5      b       4     3       3       3
6      c       5     4       4       4
7      c       5     5       5       5
```

I used following codes.

```
tmp1 = df1[df1.value1 == 'b'].iloc[:, 2:]
tmp2 = df2.iloc[1:, 2:]
```

tmp1 = tmp2 can update values in tmp1, but when I use following

```
df1[df1.value1 == 'b'].iloc[:, 2:]= tmp2
```

It doesn't update the values in df1 as shown below.

```
  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
0      a       1     1.0     1.0     1.0
1      a       2     2.0     2.0     2.0
2      a       3     3.0     3.0     3.0
3      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
4      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
5      b       4     NaN     NaN     NaN
6      c       5     NaN     NaN     NaN
7      c       5     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Why it happens and how can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: `df2` has 6 rows of data, but there are 5 `NaN` rows in `df1`. I see that your expected output skipped the first row of `df2`, and filled using rows 2 through 6. Specifically how do you plan to pick rows from `df2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it's doing:

```
tmp1 = df1[df1.value1 == 'b'].iloc[:, 2:]
```

Methods are applied *sequentially*, so `df1[df1.value1 == 'b']` keeps only rows `3, 4, 5` from `df1`. But this isn't what you want, you want to update *all rows starting from the first instance* your condition is satisfied.

Instead, first find the required index.

```
idx = df1['value1'].eq('b').values.argmax()
```

You then need to **explicitly assign** the last *n* rows from `df2`:

```
df1.iloc[idx:, 2:] = df2.iloc[-(len(df1.index)-idx):, 2:].values

print(df1)

  value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
0      a       1     1.0     1.0     1.0
1      a       2     2.0     2.0     2.0
2      a       3     3.0     3.0     3.0
3      b       4     2.0     2.0     1.0
4      b       4     2.0     2.0     2.0
5      b       4     3.0     3.0     3.0
6      c       5     4.0     4.0     4.0
7      c       5     5.0     5.0     5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the nan values using index alignment use pandas fillna

```
df1.fillna(df2)
```

Add inplace if you want to update df1

```
df1.fillna(df2, inplace=True)
```

-

- edit for case without aligned indexes:

If indexes of target and replacement values are not aligned, they can be aligned so that the dataframe fillna method can be used.

To align the indexes, get the indexes of rows containing nans in df1 to be replaced, filter df2 to include replacement values and then assign the replacement indexes from df1 as the index of df2.  Then use fillna to transfer values from df2 to df1.

```
# in this case, find index values when df1.value1 is greater than or equal to 'b'
# (alternately could be indexes of rows containing nans)
idx = df1.index[df1.value1 >= 'b']
# get the section of df2 which will provide replacement values
# limit length to length of idx
align_df = df2[1:len(idx) + 1]
# set the index to match the nan rows from df1
align_df.index = idx
# use auto-alignment with fillna to transfer values from align_df(df2) to df1
df1.fillna(align_df)

# or can use df1.combine_first(align_df) because of the matching target and replacement indexes
```

Comment: The problem is in OP's example the indices are *not* aligned.

Comment: Yes I realize that.  I wasn't sure what the OP wanted due to skipping one row, etc.  Thanks